# Generate MVC3 chart from data in SQL database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I want to create an MVC chart from data from an SQL database; calculating the number of associates that specialise in different subjects.

However I keep receiving the following error:

> Specified method is not supported.

**My code:**

```
public ActionResult SubjectChart()
{
    var db = new AssociateDBEntities();
    var data = db.SpecialistSubjects;

    var Chart = new Chart(width: 400, height: 200, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
       .AddTitle("Specialist subject")
       .AddSeries(chartType: "pie")
       .DataBindTable(dataSource: data, xField: "SubjectName")
       .Write();

    return null;
}
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: It's considered best practice to at least state the *type of the exception*, *exception message* and the *line where the error occurs* when asking on StackOverflow. We are not psychics.

Comment: Sorry. I have broke it down and added in the error message that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `null`, so you will get an error. You should return the appropiate result, and render the `Chart` in your view.

Basically the `.Write` method of `Chart` writes the image data required for the chart to display. You should either assign it to a property in your model and write it out in your View, or call `.Write` from within the view. Just calling `.Write` inside the controller does nothing.

This is how a controller method would look like:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Chart chart = new Chart(600, 400)
            .AddSeries(yValues: new int[] {100, 125, 90})
            .AddTitle("Cool graph");

        this.ViewBag.Chart = chart;            
        return View();
    }
```

And then create a simple View:

```
@ViewBag.Chart.Write()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how I would do this? Sorry this is the first time I've used mvc charts and really want to be able to use it. Thanks!

Comment: When running this I get the following error: `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the data source. Is your `data` variable null ?